# Burton: ENT: Chapter $1$

Tags: number-theory

I was reading up Burton's Elementary Number Theory and in the first chapter I encountered the following lines:

> Induction enters in showing that $n!$ as a function of positive integers exists and is unique; we shall make no attempt however to give the argument.

So, I was wondering if someone could sketch a proof of these statements or give me some hints which would help me complete the proof because as of now I am completely clueless.

Comment: Induction is a powerful method of proof, and using it to prove the existence and uniqueness of $n!$ is an overkill's overkill.

The function $f(n) = 1 \cdot 2 \cdot \ldots \cdot n$ for $n \geq 1$, and $f(0)=1$ exists by the very fact that we just wrote a formula for it.  As for "uniqueness", I don't even understand why it is in question.  Uniqueness is examined when a *problem* (i.e., an object defined by a set of properties) potentially has multiple solutions, and we show that there is only one (i.e., unique) solution.

Google for "arnold on teaching mathematics" and "bourbakism".

Answer (score 0):

Presumably we define $n!$  via the recursion:  $F(1)=1$ and $F(n)=nF(n-1)$, yes?

Existence:  Of course there is a function such that $F(1)=1$.  Assume inductively that we have successfully found some $F(2),F(3),\cdots,F(n-1)$ such that the recursion holds.  Then we define $F(n)$ to be $nF(n-1)$ and, of course, the recursion now holds for the extended sequence.

Uniqueness.  Suppose we have two two functions $F(n)$ and $G(n)$ which satisfy the defining relations.  We want to prove that $F(n)=G(n)$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$.  Of course $F(1)=G(1)$ (they are both $1$).  Suppose we have shown $F(i)=G(i)$ for $i\in \{1,\cdots,n-1\}$.  In particular we are assuming that $F(n-1)=G(n-1)$.  But then $F(n)=nF(n-1)=nG(n-1)=G(n)$ so the inductive step is complete.